# Is a constrained optimization problem equalivant to its Lagrangian form?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

For the following problem:

$\text{min:}\ f(x)\\
s.t. \ g(x)\leq t$

Is the above problem equalivant to the following problem?

$\text{min:}\ f(x) + \lambda g(x) \\
s.t. \ \lambda\geq0$

where $t$ and $\lambda$ are variables. It seems equalivant, because if we increase $\lambda$, $t$ tend to be decrease, if we decrease $\lambda$, then $t$ tend to be increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two problem formulations are equivalent for some choice of $\lambda$, at least if $g(x)$ is non-negative; the problem is that in general there's no way to figure out which $\lambda$ will give you the solution corresponding to $g(x) \leq t$.

Comment: @2566092 Do you think for a fixed $t$, there exists a fixed $\lambda$ to make the problem equivalent?

Comment: @user137273 Yes, that's what I was saying. Note that there might not be a bijection between $t$ and $\lambda$ though, if the optimal solution occurs for $g(x) = t_0 < t$

Comment: @2566092 Do you have proofs or THMs to support your comment? Any materials suggest me to read? Many thanks :)